# How to add custom php in plugin settings?

Tags: plugin

I need to display iframe in plugin settings. Iframe will be have src="https://somepage.../<=$adminEmail?>/<=$domain?>". So i need to show iframe and pass parameters of admin login and page domain with php.

I use `<scriptfile>example.script.php</scriptfile>` to show such iframe after plugin install. Is there something methods like this to display php content in plugin description?

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating a module instead because it offers more possibilities.

https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Creating_a_simple_module/Developing_a_Basic_Module

Here's the script that shows messages:

https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Creating_a_simple_module/Adding_an_install-uninstall-update_script_file